# Operação de liberar uma lista circular

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Eu estou em dúvida na implementação do método de liberar a memória de uma lista circular encadeada:

```
void liberarLista() {

   if(head == NULL)
     return; //retorna original(NULL);

    lista *aux, *temp = head;
    while(temp->prox != head) {
        aux = temp;
        temp = temp->prox;
        free(aux);
    }
    head = NULL;
}
```

No material que estou lendo ele libera depois do `while` o `head`, mas ocorre `segmentatium fault`, mas não sei se é necessário já que o `aux` libera o primeiro nó (`head`);

Comment: Após a primeira iteração de seu while já irá gerar um erro, pois você tenta acessar o endereço de memória apontada por  Head, no entanto não existe mais, pois acabou de ser liberada.

Comment: Adicione mais informações para que possamos ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa de dois ponteiros: um apontando para um elemento inicial, nesse caso o head, e outro apontando para o ponteiro "anterior" ao head em relação à lista, caso contrário seu ponteiro vai acabar perdendo referência e apontar para lixo na memória.

Não cheguei a testar o código, mas dessa forma deve funcionar:

```
void liberarLista() 
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return; //retorna original(NULL);

    // Inicia temp apontando para head
    lista *temp = head;

    // Faz temp pular elementos da lista até que aponte para
    // o elemento anterior a head
    while (temp->prox != head)
        temp = temp->prox;

    // Desaloca tudo enquanto temp não aponta para head
    while (temp != head)
    {
        temp->prox = head->prox;
        free(head);
        head = temp->prox;
    }

    // Saiu do loop, temp finalmente aponta para head
    // Agora só precisa desalocar o último elemento 
    free(head); 
    head = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por ora eu vou supor que sua lista seja algo como

```
typedef struct list{
   int ID;
   struct list *next;
} list, *listp;
```

E também que ela seja puramente circular, e não algo como uma base linear ligada num fim circular.

Acredito que é contraproducente criar um ponteiro que vai andar por toda a lista com o único objetivo de achar o penúltimo elemento. É uma redundância óbvia demais.

Pensando um pouco, creio que tem uns casinhos limítrofes a tratar - lista vazia, lista de um elemento só...

Enfim, a ideia é tratar a lista circular como se ela fosse linear. 
Para isso, vou usar dois ponteiros: um deles aponta para o elemento que será eliminado, e o outro aponta para o elemento seguinte.

```
void libera_lista(listp HEAD){

  if (HEAD == NULL)
     return;
  if (HEAD->next == HEAD){ /*A lista tem apenas um elemento*/
    free(HEAD);
    return;
  } 
  aux0 = HEAD->next;
  aux1 = aux0->next;
  while(aux1 != HEAD){
    free(aux0);
    aux0 = aux1;
    aux1 = aux1->next;
  }
  free(aux0);
  free(HEAD);
}
```

Acho que é isso. Não cheguei a testar, porém.